# Use and access a Mongodb Realm in separate Library Project Xamarin & AutoFac

Tags: mongodb, xamarin, realm, autofac

I have a small simple app that I have been working on for quite a while. It needs a small in the cloud DB and sync would be nice. After looking at several possible ways of doing this I stumbled on Realm with sync to MongoDB atlas. Just seems perfect. Authentication, etc. I have used AutoFac for my DI containers and there is where the problems started. I get a Fody error. I was using a routine for registering all the containers in the assembly which worked like a lead pipe sync until I added Realm. I think if I can create a separate library project and don't use AutoFac and use it from the Xamarin project done deal. My problem with that is I am kind of lost on how to untangle the GitHub example to achieve that? Any help is appreciated.

Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.NoConstructorsFoundException
Message=No accessible constructors were found for the type 'QuickJournal_ProcessedByFody'.
Source=Autofac
StackTrace:
at Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.DefaultConstructorFinder.GetDefaultPublicConstructors (System.Type type) [0x0002e] in /*/src/Autofac/Core/Activators/Reflection/DefaultConstructorFinder.cs:56
at Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.DefaultConstructorFinder.FindConstructors (System.Type targetType) [0x00000] in /*/src/Autofac/Core/Activators/Reflection/DefaultConstructorFinder.cs:47
at Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.ReflectionActivator.ConfigurePipeline (Autofac.Core.IComponentRegistryServices componentRegistryServices, Autofac.Core.Resolving.Pipeline.IResolvePipelineBuilder pipelineBuilder) [0x0001c] in /*/src/Autofac/Core/Activators/Reflection/ReflectionActivator.cs:86
at Autofac.Core.Registration.ComponentRegistration.BuildResolvePipeline (Autofac.Core.IComponentRegistryServices registryServices, Autofac.Core.Resolving.Pipeline.IResolvePipelineBuilder pipelineBuilder) [0x00047] in /*/src/Autofac/Core/Registration/ComponentRegistration.cs:278
at Autofac.Core.Registration.ComponentRegistration.BuildResolvePipeline (Autofac.Core.IComponentRegistryServices registryServices) [0x0002a] in /*/src/Autofac/Core/Registration/ComponentRegistration.cs:249
at Autofac.Core.Registration.ComponentRegistryBuilder.Build () [0x00024] in /*/src/Autofac/Core/Registration/ComponentRegistryBuilder.cs:92
at Autofac.ContainerBuilder.Build (Autofac.Builder.ContainerBuildOptions options) [0x00038] in /*/src/Autofac/ContainerBuilder.cs:166
at QuickJournal.App..ctor () [0x00036] in C:\Realm_Tests\QuickJournal\QuickJournal\QuickJournal\App.xaml.cs:28
at QuickJournal.Droid.MainActivity.OnCreate (Android.OS.Bundle savedInstanceState) [0x00019] in C:\Realm_Tests\QuickJournal\QuickJournal\QuickJournal.Android\MainActivity.cs:19
at Android.App.Activity.n_OnCreate_Landroid_os_Bundle* (System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr native__this, System.IntPtr native_savedInstanceState) [0x00010] in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/obj/Release/monoandroid10/android-30/mcw/Android.App.Activity.cs:2713
at (wrapper dynamic-method) Android.Runtime.DynamicMethodNameCounter.7(intptr,intptr,intptr)

Comment: you haven't included any code.  You haven't told us what specific error you are getting - just "I get a Fody error".  "how to untangle the GitHub example" - which example are you talking about?  Please read [ask] for guidance on writing a good on-topic question.

Comment: Showed the error but not sure how it adds more than I said. The problem is in the Realm package they link it to Fody and somehow several Fody classes are not registered under the hood.